# Passing variable to method in another class

Tags: c#, console-application

I am building a game where you are going to be able to bet a amount of points.

When you bet I get the value the user types in like this:

**Class Xyz.cs**

```
public static void Bet(int betAmount)
{
    Console.Write("How many points do you want to bet? ");
    int bet = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Now t´when you have made the bet there is a dice that rolls and depending on what the value the dice gets you are going to lose or gain points.

And I try to call the `int` **bet** here:

**Class abc.cs**

```
public static void GainPoints()
{
    PlayerPoints = PlayerPoints + bet * 5;
}
```

But bet gets the red underscore and if I hover over it it I get this error:

> The name 'bet' does not consist in the current context

The property `PlayerPoints` is private.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

The two methods is in separate classes.

Comment: Yes, you have declared the variable bet as part of the Bet method so the variable will not be visible to GainPoints().

Comment: Change your static method to accept a parameter of type int, and pass it in like so, GainPoints(bet); Change method signature to public static void GainPoints(int bet) {}

Comment: I'm wondering who is down voting all the answers and why. From what I've seen, the answers aren't that bad.

Comment: @Tyler: Well wonder no more... it was me. I was a bit slow adding my reasons but I have done so now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the `bet` variable is local to the `Bet` function and cannot be accessed by any methods outside of it.

It would make more sense for your `Bet` function to return the value of the bet for starters, and rename it to something more sensible:

```
public static int GetBet(int betAmount)
{
    Console.Write("How many points do you want to bet? ");
    int bet = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.ReadLine();
    return bet;
}
```

Then you can pass the value into your other function when you call it. Change your `GainPoints` function like so:

```
public static void GainPoints(int bet)
{
    PlayerPoints = PlayerPoints + bet * 5;
}
```

Then you call the functions something like this, for example:

```
int bet = Class1.GetBet(betAmount);
Class2.GainPoints(bet);
```

---

Now, any experience developer would probably recognise that the design here isn't the best. It would probably be better to have some sort of `Bet` class that tracks information on the bet and passes it around as needed. However, it would be far too broad to go into those kind of details here.